# Using a model inside a helper

Tags: php, architecture

I've a quick question related to the software architecure. In my application I have a model which contains a method to check the environment the application works in. Let's say the model is called "AppModel".

So, the AppModel::isDevEnv() indicates whether the app is runnig in production or development. It's easy to call this method inside others models, components etc.

The problem is when I want to check the environement inside a view. I created a helper with a propriety method inside just to cover the method from the model and return the result coming from exactly model's method.

```
class AppModel {
    public function isDevEnv() {
        return boolean;
    }
}

class AppHelper {
    public static function isDevEnv() {
        $app = new AppModel();
        return $app->isDevEnv();
    }
}
```

Is it correct approach? Maybe it's a little bit overcomplicated? Maybe I should just make a static method inside a model and call it whenever I would like to call it?

Comment: This looks wrong. `isDev` looks like a configuration variable that should be parsed and used at startup - without more context im only guessing, but this certainly smells bad

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. It's a legacy system with lots of this kind of flowers inside, so let's consider this certain case.

Comment: Is it truly model specific? Unless you can have models that determine which environment they are using on their own, I'd put this outside of the model scope.

Comment: OK, well i know the pain of working on such systems, but its still very hard to give good advice without understanding how the system works.

Comment: @Steve To indicate the enviroment I use a condition similar to this one: if (defined(CONSTANT_VAR) && $otherVar && $anotherOne){//then go}. The condition is used many times in a few places (DRY). I would like to put it into one place to keep the clearness of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a legacy system I would recommend to refactor it to the desirable solution. If you want to have this helper or it is a required step for further refactoring then do it.

In general I would inject services which behave differently based on the environment instead of checking the environment inside your models. But it might not be easy with legacy system.

Comment: I am going to refactor it this year. For now I've to find a solution which does not hurt my heart ;-) Thanks for the insight!